# Need help to make a request properly via the parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, parameters

This is the first time I have to do this, and I'm really struggling.

To be short i reveive some data from my form, parse all data, and redirect to a url with the data parsed.

```
const tags = qs.stringify({tags: tabTags})
    const ingredients = qs.stringify({ingredients: tabIngredients})
    const name = qs.stringify({name: data.name})
    const url = `/recipes/all/search?${tags}&${ingredients}&${name}`;
    navigation(url);
```

We can already see that the code is not the best code ever..

URL look like : "http://127.0.0.1:5173/recipes/all/search?tags%5B0%5D=Vegan&tags%5B1%5D=Healthy&ingredients%5B0%5D=Courgette&name=ss"

Now, I come on this page

```
export default function RecipeSearch() {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
    const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const tags = queryParameters.getAll("tags");
    const name = queryParameters.get("name");
    const ingredients = queryParameters.getAll('ingredients');
    const {data, isError, isLoading } = useFetchRecipe({tags:searchParams.getAll('tags'), recipe:searchParams.get('name'), ingredients:searchParams.getAll('ingredients')})
    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Wait...</p>
    }
    if (isError) {
        return <p>Error ! </p>
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col mt-20 -ml-14">
            { console.log('tags',tags )}

        {data.map((recipe) => (
            <Recipe {...recipe}/>
        ))}
       
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to retrieve the params and give them to "useFetchRecipe" and finally do my request.
But i can't retrieve the url.
I really don't know how to do this "proprely" with a hashed url as I showed above.
Thanks a lot if anyone can help me !

Already tried to get the url params with some techniques but none works